# KotlinJS unresolved reference element.style

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I want to change the style of an element created using `document.createElement("button")`.

I tried using:

```
element.style.width = "50px"
```

However, the style field cannot be found.

Comment: Please provide a comment on how this question could be improved or whether sharing knowledge QA style is not appreciated instead of just downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Element` needs to be cast to the more specific `HTMLElement` type:

```
val button = document.createElement("button") as HTMLElement
button.style.width = "50px"
```